# ASP repeater overflowing from div

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm having issues with my asp repeater. Basically it reads in from a database and writes out repeating divs.. The problem is that the h4 is spilling out over the div, any ideas on how to solve this? Its only when i use the <%Eval that I get this problem. The divs I've manually typed out are fine and not overspilling

HTML

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Headline], [Story], [image] FROM [News]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="news">
                <div class="headline">
                <div id="spacer">
                <h5><%#Eval("Headline") %></h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="newsFoot">
                <h4><%#Eval("Story") %></h4>
                <img src="<%#Eval("image") %>" width ="290px" />



                </div>
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You should share the resulting page, if possible. Since the css will tell a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears not to be your code, but rather your CSS.

Make sure that your H4 tag CSS has an appropriate height value.